# How does one make a Model perform a method on itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class MyAwesomeClass

  def foobar
    puts "trip!"
  end
```

So that I can perform :

```
MyAwesomeClass.foobar

=> "trip!"
```

I keep getting :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `foobar' for MyAwesomeClass:Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyAwesomeClass
  def self.foobar
    puts "trip!"
  end 
end
```

Using "self" makes the method a class instance method

Comment: "static method" is not the official term for this. "class instance method" is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev kk, is there a reason why they don't call it "static" other than trying to be different?

Comment: Of course there are reasons. But this is out of scope here. :)